# Possible values of Radius of Convergence based on divergent and convergent x's

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am having problems with the following exercise:

Given the Maclaurin series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n $ 
is divergent for $x=-6,8$ and convergent for $x=-4,6$. What are the possible values for the radius of convergence, $R$?

The given answer is $6$, but I don't know how to deduce this.

Comment: Hint: your series is centered around $0$, so trying the largest interval $(-a,a)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ which your series is convergent on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the circle of convergence is at $x=0$ because the terms are of the form $c_n(x-0)^n$.

Divergence for $x=-6$ means $R\leq 6$ while convergence for $x=6$ means $R\geq 6$, so $\boxed{R=6}$.

Behavior at the other points doesn't matter.